# Singular Points on Algebraic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, algebraic-curves

What does it mean for a point on an algebraic curve (over any field) to be singular? Over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ is means that all derivatives vanish, but how does this definition generalise to general fields?

Answer (score 5):

Zariski introduced in 1947 the definition of regularity used today, namely:
  On a curve $C$ defined over a completely arbitrary base field $k$ a point $P\in C$ is said to be regular (or non-singular) if and only if the local ring $\mathcal O_{C,P}$ is a discrete valution ring.

By contrast the curve $C$ is said to be smooth  at the point $P\in C$ if all points $\bar P\in  C_{\bar k }$  mapped onto $P$ after the base change map $ C_{\bar k }\to C$ ($\bar k$=algebraic closure  of $k$) are regular on $C_{\bar k }$.
Smoothness (but not regularity!) can be checked by the usual Jacobian criterion involving partial derivatives and, most importantly, smoothness implies regularity.
The converse ot this implication however is false: here is

**An example of a regular but not smooth point $Q$**

Let $k$ be a non perfect field of odd characteristic $p\geq 3$ and  $a\in k$ be an element without a $p$-th root in $k$.
The plane curve $C\subset \mathbb A^2_k$ defined by $y^2+x^p-a=0$ is regular at all its points but not smooth at the point $Q\in C$ defined by the maximal ideal ideal $\langle  y,x^p-a \rangle\subset \mathcal O(C)=k[x,y]=k[X,Y]/\langle  Y,X^p-a \rangle$

Comment: This would be hard to generalize to all commutative rings with unity. But I agree the OP asked for fields only.

Comment: @Robert *This would be hard to generalize to all commutative rings with unity* Really? Just ask a question about that and we'll see...

Comment: I never said that EGA IV, Théorème 17.5.1 was hard to understand when it is known. I mean that it is hard to came up with. That is, that the road from Zariski to Serre and then Grothendieck took more than ten years. And also that flatness was not that easy to came up with.

Comment: And obviously by *all* I was at least meaning of finite presentation. ;-)

Comment: locally, of course ;-)

Comment: Some precisions on the relationship between regularity and smoothness over a general field $k$: 1) regularity at a rational point can actually be checked via the Jacobian criterion, just not at all points over $\bar{k}$. 2) regularity is invariant under separable field extensions of $k$. In particular smoothness and regularity can only differ when the base field is imperfect, and only at (closed) points with non-separable residue field. This explains why the example has to be over a non-perfect field, and concern a point with totally inseparable residue field.

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking (meaning I will voluntarily not being precise) being nonsingular is not being smooth. Over $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{C}$ you can define being smooth be the fact that the jacobian is invertible, as in the implict function theorem, and "being invertible" for the jacobian is an algebraic statement (meaning for instance that some ideal is equal to some whole ring) that you can translate to any field, and in fact any ring. (Modulo some additive assumptions/definitions.) I don't like pointing to wikipedia, but you could start with [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_morphism) and come back if you need more EGA 4 references.